# Flask using id to personalise landing page

Tags: python, flask

I am working through the flask tutorial. I am trying to tinker with the tutorial code to better understand it. Below is the code for the homepage. It accesses all the posts people have written on the blog.

```
@bp.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    posts = db.execute(
        'SELECT p.id, title, body, created, author_id, username'
        ' FROM post p JOIN user u ON p.author_id = u.id'
        ' ORDER BY created DESC'
    ).fetchall()
    return render_template('blog/index.html', posts=posts)
```

I was trying to adjust it so that it only shows posts which that user wrote. As a starting point, I tried to pass in id as an input variable to the index() function, much like the function get_post() does (see below)

```
@bp.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required

...

def get_post(id, check_author=True):
    post = get_db().execute(
        'SELECT p.id, title, body, created, author_id, username'
        ' FROM post p JOIN user u ON p.author_id = u.id'
        ' WHERE p.id = ?',
        (id,)
    ).fetchone()

    if post is None:
        abort(404, "Post id {0} doesn't exist.".format(id))

    if check_author and post['author_id'] != g.user['id']:
        abort(403)

    return post
```

However, this throws an error with id not recognised as an input variable. This happens when I add the @login_required, and when I tried changing the ip address to '/int:id//' which was used in another function which took in id as an input.

thank you for your help:))

Comment: Did you write it like that? ```/<int:id>```

Comment: so for a different function called update(), it had '/<int:id>/update' in the route, so i figured i would need '/<int:id>//'

Comment: You only need the trailing slashes if you attach additional parts. Look [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules). I'm still trying to find the reason for the issue. I assume that the user is logged in? If so, you do not necessarily need the parameter, but can use the variable ```current_user``` to query its id. Still, it should work with your approach too.

Comment: If you use ```/<int:id>```, the page should be accessible via ```http://127.0.0.1: 5000/1``` and the id should be assigned the value 1. Is there an error message within the console? Please write me the error message.

Comment: perfect thank you that works:))